# How do I create type for array of ProvidedType?

Tags: f#, type-providers

How do I create type for array of ProvidedType? 
In other words, what is an alternative to `MakeArrayType` on generic `Type` class?

EDIT:
The issue is that when I'm trying `MakeArrayType`, TP fails.

Here is an example to reproduce the error: https://gist.github.com/dsevastianov/46d1a8495c4af46a9875

Client fails with "The operation 'UnderlyingSystemType' on item 'Birch[]' should not be called on provided type, member or parameter"

Comment: What's wrong with calling `MakeArrayType` on a `ProvidedTypeDefinition`?

Comment: I'm getting "The opperation 'UnderlyingSystemType' on item 'MyProvidedType[]' should not be called on provided type, member or parameter".

Comment: Could you provide a minimal repro?  That should just work.

Comment: Right, I think I might have screwed up myself, looking into it.

Comment: Well, no, I didn't. Here is a repro: https://gist.github.com/dsevastianov/46d1a8495c4af46a9875

Comment: Good repro - the issue is limited to generated types; not sure if the problem is in ProvidedTypes or a compiler bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in ProvidedTypes.fs.  Just ensure that `GetUnderlyingSystemType` is implemented for the `ProvidedSymbolType` class.  This seems to work fine:

```
override this.UnderlyingSystemType = 
    match kind with 
    | SymbolKind.SDArray
    | SymbolKind.Array _
    | SymbolKind.Pointer
    | SymbolKind.FSharpTypeAbbreviation _
    | SymbolKind.ByRef -> upcast this
    | SymbolKind.Generic gty -> gty.UnderlyingSystemType
```

Comment: Right, my version has `ByRef` case set to notRequired. It did the trick, thanks a lot!